# CSV upload filtering in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, csv

I am currently adding a CSV email-list option to an existing AngularJS-based site. I use Papa Parse to parse the CSV straight to objects. What I need to do is have these results add up to the HTML and filter them so that only the email addresses will appear in the results, which will then later be counted for sending. How can I filter a CSV parse reult so that it only displays email addresses and ignores all the other values? Naturally, this would have to be done using just Angular to avoid conflicts.

Here's the Papa Parse section:

```
$('input[type=file]').parse({
            config: {header: true,
              step: function(results, handle) {
              rows = _.union(rows, results.data);
                console.log("Row data:", results.data);
                console.log("Row errors:", results.errors);


                // Define HTML output
                //
                for (var i = 0; i < $files.length; i++) {
                      var file = $files[i];
                    }

                    $.each(results.data, function(i, el) {
                      var row = $('<ng-form ng-repeat="row in rows"/>');
                      row.append($('').text(i));
                      $.each(el, function(j, cell) {
                        if (cell !== "")
                          row.append($('<td type="text" class="form-control csv-form medium" ng-model="row.email"></td>').text(cell));
                      });
                      $("#results").append(row);
                    });
                  }
            }
          });


      function FileUploadCtrl(scope) {
              scope.setFiles = function(element) {
              scope.$apply(function(scope) {
                console.log('files:', element.files);
                // Turn the FileList object into an Array
                  scope.files = []
                  for (var i = 0; i < element.files.length; i++) {
                    scope.files.push(element.files[i])
                }
             scope.progressVisible = false
          });
      };

      scope.uploadFile = function() {
                  var fd = new FormData()
                  for (var i in scope.files) {
                      fd.append("uploadedFile", scope.files[i])
                  }
                  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest()
                  xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", uploadProgress, false)
                  xhr.addEventListener("load", uploadComplete, false)
                  xhr.addEventListener("error", uploadFailed, false)
                  xhr.addEventListener("abort", uploadCanceled, false)
                  xhr.open("POST", "/fileupload")
                  scope.progressVisible = true
                  xhr.send(fd)
               }
            }
          }
       );    
    },
```

This should be the HTML part:

`<div ng-file-select="onFileSelect($files, angular.element(this).scope())" data-multiple="true" ng-list ng-model="csv" id="fileToUpload" title="Select file" ng-change="angular.element(this).scope().setFiles(this)">
            <a href="" ng-click="edit()"><i class="fa fa-upload"></i> {{ 'Import CSV' | Translator }}</a>`

Comment: If you can share some code that would be helpful. Cant help you just like this. But since Papa Parse gives you the object and the row will be an array of string of emails. You just need to add it to the scope.

Comment: Ok, added the code snippets now.

Comment: You cannot append angular js directives from the the javascript like that - the angular directive need to be digested to be rendered. Angular supports two way data binding - right? So just store data in a scope variable